# Transpose XML directly in file

Tags: xml, xsd

I've got a data file in xml:

```
<person>
<name>Test</name>
<birth>1.1.1999 12:00</birth>
</person>
```

Now I got two questions:
1) Can I transpose the table (maybe with some stylesheet) such that it looks like this:

name |....Name1................Name2
birth |.....1.1.99 12:00........2.2.98 11:00

2) Can I format it to Datetime? I got a format which is: 1 January 1990 11:00:00, but I want a diffrent formatting.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  The simplest way, for most readers of sites like Stack Overflow, is to write a program in the programming language of your choice to call a parser, consume the document, build appropriate data structures, restructure it, and serialize the newly restructured information.  In practice these steps are often interleaved.

Different people will have different favorite ways to solve problems like this; you can use XSLT, you can use XQuery, you can use PHP or Java or Python or Perl or Cobol or Haskell or ...

You will probably get more concrete help if you say which programming language you are interested in using; your question suggests you want to use XSD for this purpose, but that makes no sense:  XSD is not a tool for restructuring XML documents.

Comment: I wrote my code in Python. But my problem is that I parse my elements manually.

So I have a XML template:
    {%for person in plist %}
    <person>
    <name>{{person.name}}}</name>
    <birth>{{person.date}}</birth>
    </person>
    {%endfor%}.  Am I forced to build tree and generate the file by some packages?

Comment: No one except possibly your employer is able to force you to use a library package you don't want to use.  I believe that many Python programmers find the SAX and DOM interfaces to XML parsers provided with Python helpful in processing XML, but if you like writing parsers, you may certainly roll your own.  But maybe I don't understand your real concerns here.